# Why does Viewport Render Image in "Rendered" Viewport Shading mode gives black/transparent

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Below attached is a screenshot of what I can actually see in my viewport when switched to **rendered view** with **transparency** turned on in render settings

[image]

This is exactly what I would like to have as an output when I'm giving the command of "**Viewport Render Image**"

Instead, below attached is what I get

[image]

Turning off the transparency and then giving "Viewport Render Image" gives a completely black image as output

Is there any way I could get what I see in the Rendered Viewport Shading Mode as an output of "Viewport Render Image"?

Here is a link to the .blend file

[image]

Comment: this should "normally" work...unfortunately you didn't show us any of your settings except transparent check. So providing your blend file is a good idea so we can check it out

Comment: sorry about that, I've attached the blend file
thank you